# How do I fix these blurry artifacts?

Tags: rendering

[image]

How would I fix the artifacting?

Renderer: Eeve
  Blend file: http://www.mediafire.com/file/aoq4aegv55u5g21/monkeys.blend/file

Comment: Please use the [edit] link at the bottom of your question (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) and add more information. We can't guess how you set up your project or your textures or render settings or what render engine you are using.

Comment: StackExchange is a Q&A site which values questions that show you've made an effort towards solving the issue.
The [How do I ask a good question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)
page from the Help Center may help you improve your question. Please try to describe what you've tried so far
and why this didn't give you the desired result.